# postgresql sql files not executing properly

Tags: postgresql, transactions

**Background**

I have a little program that will loop through a bunch of .sql files and run them against a postgresql database. The last thing each .sql file is supposed to do is update a version number in a specific table.

For example consider the following file list:

```
 file1.sql
 file2.sql
```

The files are run in descending order.  (file2 , then file1) The sql in each file looks similar to this:

```
\c widgets;

DO $$
BEGIN  -- anonymous function starts
--      BEGIN -- start transaction 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablex) THEN

        -- do a bunch of stuff to the database. 
        -- update version number
        UPDATE widgets_control SET version = '1';

        END IF;
        --COMMIT;
END
$$;
```

File 2 would run first... and updates the version to 2, and File 1 would update it 1 etc..

**Problem**

When I run these files individually / manually each file properly sets the version number. 
When I run them via my test script, file 1 is NOT updating the version number.  But the other sql statements in file1.sql are applied.

**Test Script Code**

The code that tries to loop through and run all .sql files looks like this: (lua code)

```
  for index, value in ipairs (sql_change_files) do
       os.execute('psql -U postgres -f '..value)
       --os.execute('sleep 10')
  end
```

**Question**
Have I declared the "DO" block properly? I added the DO because I wanted to use the IF EXISTS statement.

Have I created a transaction properly?  As you can see I was playing around with BEGIN/COMMIT

If my transaction is set up properly, I can't think of why running the two files back to back would fail.  As you can see I've also played around with the sleep command... to see if it was a race condition of sorts.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: but the `if` seems totally useless. Just run the update, if there are no rows in the table, then nothing gets updated

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name for simplicity's sake I didn't go into the IF ... but it is needed.

Comment: `UPDATE widgets_control SET version = '1' WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablex);`

Comment: If `file2` updates the same version row then you will not see version 1.

Comment: sorry @joop i don't understand your comment.  The update should only happen after the other statements in between the IF and the Update run...

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto except that file2 runs first.  then file 1.  I've updated my question to make it more clear.